# An error occurred while installing commonmarker (0.17.13), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, bundler

**Issue**: When executing `bundle install` via terminal it fails to install dependencies.

**Log (partial)**:

```
   Password: 
Installing commonmarker 0.17.13 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/tmp/bundler20190915-6718-b0qbe8commonmarker-0.17.13/gems/commonmarker-0.17.13/ext/commonmarker
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20190915-6718-1610j54.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/tmp/bundler20190915-6718-b0qbe8commonmarker-0.17.13/gems/commonmarker-0.17.13
for inspection.
Results logged to
/tmp/bundler20190915-6718-b0qbe8commonmarker-0.17.13/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/commonmarker-0.17.13/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing commonmarker (0.17.13), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install commonmarker -v '0.17.13' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  github-pages was resolved to 198, which depends on
    jekyll-commonmark-ghpages was resolved to 0.1.5, which depends on
      jekyll-commonmark was resolved to 1.3.1, which depends on
        commonmarker
```

---

**OS**: GNU/Linux

**gem -v**: 2.5.2.1

**ruby -v**: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: Make sure that `gem install commonmarker -v '0.17.13' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

Answer (score 14):

This solved for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Followed by

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me:

```
$ cd APP_ROOT
$ su
# apt install rbenv
# rbenv global
# gem install bundler
# rbenv rehash
# gem clean
$ bunlde install
```